# Sponsoring 3 applicants for Standard Visitor to the UK (mother, mother in law and aunt)

Tags: visas, uk

Is it possible and how likely can get an approved Standard visitor visa if we sponsor 3 applicants?
We are couple with no children from the philippines. My spouse is under depandant visa and i got the ILR recently. I get into the UK through Tier 2 PBS. Currently, I am receiving an annual salary of GBP53,000 + Bonus of GBP10,000 + Incentives of GBP5,000. All these figures are mentioned on my Certificate of employment. My savings account has a withdrawal balance of GBP20,000.
In regards to our accommodation, we are renting a 2-bedroom semi-furnished flat.

We are inviting my mother, my mother-in-law and my aunt to visit us for one month only. And, we want to sponsor the three of them. We will shoulder all the costs including airfare, food and accommodation concerning their trip to the UK. 
Is it reasonable to do it? How likely the EO will approve their visa? Is there any problem in regards to the accommodation?
Please help and please give advise and suggestions before we file their application.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your current situation looks good and invitation sounds reasonable but that is not the only thing they are looking for. They will also focus on the applicant's current situation in their own country before making a decision. If they don't have a compelling reason to go back after the trip then you can provide all the support and still get rejected